# Escaped apostrophes and regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex, string, apostrophe, string-interpolation

I have a string that I am attempting to gather some specific data from. I'm able to narrow down that the given string (which has an escaped apostrophe \') is inside the main string. However, when I scan it for the string, using #{string}, it finds no results.

I am pretty certain that this is because when an escaped apostrophe \' is in double quotes, it becomes "Str\'ing", which is what it would look like in the main string. However, once interpolated into a regular expression, it stays as "Str\\'ing", which can't be found.

I suppose my question is how should I properly handle this? I'm sure the solution would either be a better regular expression, or a better substitution, but I don't know what those would be.

Here is some sample code:

```
text = "STR = {'Str\'ing', ... }"
thing = "Str'ing"
thing.gsub!("'") { "\\'" }
if text.include?("= {'#{thing}',") # => true
  match_data = text.scan(/([A-Z0-9\-]+) = {'#{thing}',/)
  p match_data
  # => []
end
```

Comment: Just remove `thing.gsub!("'") { "\\'" }` and you will get `match_data` as `STR`. Your `text` variable holds `STR = {'Str'ing', ... }` text. There is no literal escape symbol there. With your code, `if text.include?("= {'#{thing}',")` evaluates to false.

Comment: The text variable was an example, and probably a bad one. The text that I'm getting does not actually get simplified. I just printed the actual text, and the apostrophes were escaped as normal appearing with the backslash and apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

There's surely a better way to do this, but it seems to work for my purposes. I changed the first gsub! call to `thing.gsub!(/'/) { "\\'" }` to make the `include?` call true. Then I added an additional `thing.gsub!(/\'/) { "\\'" }` so that the regex can actually find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do away with the `gsub!` call since the `\'` will be interpreted as `'`. You can also simplify the regular expression to `/\w+ = {'#{thing}',/` since you really just need to match a single word before the = sign.
So like this

```
    text = "STR = {'Str\'ing', ...}"
    thing = 'Str\'ing'
    if text.include?("= {'#{thing}',") 
      match_data = text.scan(/\w+ = {'#{thing}',/)
      puts match_data
    end
```

Comment: Without defining thing with an escaped ', wouldn't I still need the gsub call? The "thing" variable is actually user input, which would rarely include escape symbols.

Comment: Oh, the simplified regex isn't actually the same, because \w will match lowercase letters, which is not good for my context. The "STR" in text is an abbreviation, which can only be uppercase letters, numbers, and hyphens, to my knowledge.